# Codeigniter Show All Duplicate Records in view

Tags: codeigniter

I have this working query which will fetch duplicate records in Codeigniter

```
 function getDuplicatePartNumbers()
 {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->select('part_number');
    $this->db->select('count(*)');
    //$this->db->from('orders');
    $this->db->group_by('part_number');
    $this->db->having('count(*) > 1');
    $query = $this->db->get('pending_order');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

I need to modify this since it will only return  the value that is duplicated, but it does not return all the duplicates

Example if I have

```
   id      name      

   1        jane
   2        jane
   3         joe
   4        jane
```

Only 1 jane will appear, I want all jane in this case

Any ideas?

Comment: from fisrt query you gettin just **jane** pass it in where and create another select query and pass this **jane**

Answer (score 0):

You've got the `part_number` and the `count(*)`.
Give an alias to the `count(*)`
and use it to know the number of occurrences of each record retrieved.

```
$this->db->select('count(*) as occurrences');
```